# Entering Jordan from Israel: visa on separate paper instead of passport stamp?

Tags: passport-stamps, israel, jordan

Last week, I went on a guided tour to Jordan (Jerach, Petra) from Israel. I have received a Jordan stamp in my passport, as usual.

As you might be aware, when your passport shows proof you have visited Israel, you cannot enter some Islamic countries anymore. Israel solves this by giving you a piece of paper instead of a passport stamp, however, as the Jordan stamp mentions the name of the border crossing and this gives away I've been in Israel, I cannot use my passport now to enter these countries.

I like passport stamps, so I don't mind having an extra stamp in my passport. However, I'm also interested in visiting Iran for which I now need to get a new passport.

In the hostel I was staying at, some other people went on the exact same tour, but a few days earlier. They used the same border crossing and one of those people was from the same country as me and so had the same passport. The weird thing here: they didn't receive any passport stamp, but got the stamp on a seperate piece of paper.

I've asked our guide in Jordan about this and he said this is impossible and Jordan always stamps passports. However, I've seen the piece of paper with my own eyes.

Is anyone aware of the current policy? When do you get a passport stamp and when do you get a piece of paper?

Comment: What kind of visa did you get from Jordan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on reports from multiple people, the Jordan land-border crossings with Israel WILL stamp your entry visa/stamp onto a piece of paper **if asked**.  They will not do this by default, but if you ask them to then they will most likely do so - however there is technically no guarantee they will do so, so as always it's a good idea to ask nicely!

If you are doing a tour that returns back to Israel then you should be fine with simply getting this visa stamped on a piece of paper.  However if you were planning to depart Jordan via air then it's important to be aware that the immigration staff at Queen Alia International Airport (and potentially other airports) will generally NOT stamp your exit stamp on a piece of paper even when asked, and even if your entry stamp was on a piece of paper.

This leaves you in a situation where you have an Jordanian exit stamp but no entry stamp in your passport - which can also be a sign to other countries that you entered Jordan overland from Israel.

Comment: I've never received an exit stamp from Jordan (only an entry stamp), is that the standard procedure?

Comment: @Bv202 It's possible thing have changed, but I certainly received an exit stamp when departing by air in November 2016, and have seen numerous reports of people that also received stamps.